# Should we create a YouTube account to promote our site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, video

I recently found a few YouTube videos about specific Stack Exchange site:

- [Stack Exchange English Language and Usage Overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kSVOVeZa9U),
- [Esperanto Stack Exchange! (with English subtitles)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qPry_esR3Q) (the video is in Esperanto),
- [Esperanto ĉe StackExchange! Bonvolu helpi!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iza5Gh8QNOE) (in Esperanto, without subtitles!)

So I was wondering if one of our members has a YouTube account with a few followers and would be able to create a video to promote LL SE. When I posted this question in the chat, PythonMaster suggested creating a community-shared account.

This leads to **two questions**:

- Do you think this would help attract more users to LL SE?
- Who would be willing to invest some time into this?

**Update**: YouTube videos were also asked about on Meta SE: [Featuring Stack Exchange on YouTube - Anything I Should be Aware of?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284546/featuring-stack-exchange-on-youtube-anything-i-should-be-aware-of). The question has one answer that contains the following advice:

> The most important thing is probably to make sure that people being directed here understand what type of question will be received favorably and what will be hammered by down votes and closed. (...)

Comment: This is a great idea. Are you thinking about a kind of podcast?

Comment: You know, I think that this would not only be effective, but also kinda fun. I do have a YouTube channel, but it's really small and not really related to languages at all. That said, I do have experience, and would be willing to pitch in some time and effort to see this endeavor grow.

Comment: I had thought of something in the style of the first or the third video. I don't have any experience with this yet, but it would be a learning opportunity ;-)

Comment: @fi12 A screencast is what I have in mind. (I forgot the @... in my previous comment.)

Comment: A related idea, perhaps maybe starting some sort of unofficial community blog?

Comment: @fi12 Does Stack Exchange have infrastructure for that? (I thought not.) Of course, there are many blogging services available elsewhere. This probably deserves/requires a separate meta question.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe I know Stack Exchange used to have a blogging platform but it was shut down. They still do encourage individual sites to create their own blogs if there is enough community support behind the idea. If we were to make a blog, a good choice of a platform would be Medium.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe [This](https://medium.com/universe-factory) is Worldbuilding's community blog hosted on Medium.

Comment: @fi12 A blog is worth considering. How much community support would be enough? (The number of very active users is still very small.) I might have a go at a YouTube video this weekend.

Comment: @fi12 Two things I like about Medium: it is not owned by Big Brother G##gle, and it allows you to use a Creative Commons licence.

Comment: Seems like we're not the only [ones](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4007/worldbuilding-podcast-01-lotr-and-worldbuilding-among-other-nerd-topics?cb=1): [this is their first podcast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zaofvXNn-1E).