# A community blog (Launched!)

Tags: discussion, blog

In a discussion over in [this question](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/should-we-create-a-youtube-account-to-promote-our-site), we discussed the idea of having an unofficial, community run Language Learning blog hosted on [Medium](http://medium.com).

If you've got any suggestions or comments, please leave them below.

**Add your name to the Community Wiki answer below along with a possible role you would be interested in having in the blog (writer, editor, site admin, advertising, etc.)**

**If you've got any good ideas for some blog posts, add them to the second Community Wiki answer and make sure you credit yourself for the idea.**

## The blog has [launched](https://medium.com/language-learning-blog), and we're currently looking for editors and authors to help write blog posts and maintain the blog. Add your Medium usernames if you're interested.

Comment: I'd like to have a longer community discussion about this blog, before we go live with it.  What is the intended purpose? (drive traffic here? Educate regulars? Expand on answers provided here for newbies? Link sharing/SEO for members' own blogs? etc) The answer(s) to our intended purpose will heavily inform how we move forward. I know some discussion happened on the YouTube post, but I think we should have one (or more) meta posts about the shape of this blog, before we jump the gun and launch it.

Comment: How and who is going to make the blog? Will it made via coding (i.e. HTML, Python) or by a third-party website builder (i.e. Weebly)? How will admins get appointed (i.e. email which no one knows except the owners)?

Comment: @PythonMaster From the question: "...community run Language Learning blog hosted on [Medium](medium.com)...". Medium is a blog builder, so it'll be much more convenient for us to use it. In terms of admins, I'm fairly sure that Medium has a sort of built in, editing hierarchy system -- admin, then editor, then author, or something like that.

Comment: For future reference, I created a second LL chatroom for discussion specifically about the blog.

Answer (score 1):

**Possible Roles:**

- [fi12](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/91/fi12) - Writer, Admin
- [Hatchet](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/85/hatchet) - Editor/Proofreader
- [PythonMaster](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/64/pythonmaster) - Editor/Proofreader, Admin, Unofficial [Twitter Account](https://twitter.com/Language_Blog) Manager (Username: Anthony Pham)
- [Christophe Strobbe](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/800/christophe-strobbe) - writer (can proofread posts by non-native speakers of English; can also do admin work if necessary).

Comment: Can we have all moderators be admins including original site creator(s)?

Comment: @PythonMaster The big thing here is whether all of the moderators **want** to be admins. We wouldn't want to force a responsibility upon them that they are unwilling to carry out. But to be honest, there really is no hierarchy in the blog system; everyone edits, moderates, and writes, regardless of your reputation on the main site. By the use of the term "admin", I was referring to more of a sort of system admin, who could oversee the domain and help with technical issues.

Answer (score 1):

**Blog Post Ideas:**

- Intro to our site, explaining what's within the scope of the site, intended for new users ([fi12](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/91/fi12))
- Comparing efficiency of different language learning software (using both for 30 days and then taking a fluency test at the end to see which was more effective) ([fi12](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/91/fi12))
- Featured Post of the Week - This post would be able to be featured in a sense and be an example for future posts to follow whether it would proper citing or just extremely high quality ([PythonMaster](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/64/pythonmaster))
- Sources/Articles - This would allow users and non-users to access good sources and/or articles about language learning ([PythonMaster](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/64/pythonmaster))
- Interview with users/moderators ([fi12](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/91/fi12))
- Language of the week, discussing quirks and language learning resources for various languages ([fi12](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/91/fi12))

Comment: Perhaps "Featured Post of the Week" instead of "Featured Post of the Day"? Otherwise we drain our time and energy on the blog instead of LL SE.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe If we do decide to start the blog, I'd suggest keeping some sort of list like [this](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/new-blog-post-prehistory-of-great-lakes-earth?cb=1) will all past blog posts. Worldbuilding also has the blog post set as an event so it gains greater publicity from the site.

Comment: That makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

What is our intended purpose for this blog? (this should probably be its own question, but the OP asked for comments here)

Comment: It was suggested as a way to attract more (new) users to the site. I have to admit that I don't know if it worked for other sites.

Comment: Can we attempt to find out from the other sites that have run a blog?

Comment: @Flimzy I've myself participated pretty heavily on Worldbuilding, who have one of the more prominent community blogs. I'll try to find out.

Comment: Thinking this over again, I think it would be hard to establish a connection between a blog and site growth. Even *if* you can establish a correlation, how do you establish causation (and in which direction)?

Comment: @fi12 Fellow beta site Retrocomputing recently launched their own [blog](http://meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/223/we-have-got-a-blog), where they stated the reason for starting the blog was: to "serve to publicise our site – provided that high quality content is posted on it, and backlinks are placed where relevant..." and to have a "fantastically vast wealth of information for everybody to share and enjoy."