# The state of the blog

Tags: discussion, blog

In the last meta post [about the blog](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/434/a-community-blog?cb=1), several volunteers graciously stepped up and offered their time and ideas to creating a community blog. I've also created an [LL chatroom specifically meant for discussing the blog](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47429/language-learning-blog) where we can immediately propose ideas. However, there are a few things to discuss before we actually start with the idea:

First, is having a blog practical and within the scope of what our community's users can maintain?

Secondly, as [Flimzy](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/13/flimzy) pointed out, if we do decide to start up the blog, we must first ask ourselves

> What is the intended purpose [of the blog]? (drive traffic here?
> Educate regulars? Expand on answers provided here for newbies? Link
> sharing/SEO for members' own blogs? etc) The answer(s) to our intended
> purpose will heavily inform how we move forward.

This is a vital question and needs some serious answers, and I'd like to hear your thoughts on the subject.

Have at it.

## The blog has [launched](https://medium.com/language-learning-blog), and we're currently looking for editors and authors to help write blog posts and maintain the blog. Add your Medium usernames if you're interested.

Comment: After a year or more on LL, I had NO IDEA that LL has a blog, when I found about it's existence on some meta post, it took me another half-hour to find the URL for it. And it is interesting blog, i just had no idea. Maybe it needs more promotion? Like on Tour page?

Answer (score 3):

The initial purpose of the blog is to drive more participants to LL SE. I say "initial" because it should be OK to change the blog's purpose once we have sufficient website traffic. (That will take a while, though.)

More users should mean more questions and answers (hopefully of high quality). For this reason, an important type of content on the blog should be based on high-quality answers that were submitted to the site.

The blog can also be used to highlight high-quality questions that have not received an answer yet, and describe ideas for language-related questions, such as the creation of [website with minimal pairs in arbitrary languages](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2306/800).

Updated: Possible more detailed guidance on **how to contribute**, like [this page on Sci-Fi's blog](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/contribute/).

Comment: Only answers? What about questions and other important meta posts?

Comment: @PythonMaster Does my answer look better now?