# State of the Blog - Part Two

Tags: discussion, blog

It's been a very long while since [our blog has been launched](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/446/64). Around 5 months if anyone is interested but anyways, we are improving on our stats in the last 90 days. Our blog has been visited 133 times and our articles have been read for a total of 160 minutes! Charts:

[image]
[image]
[image]

We have seen better days but there has been lots of improvement. February has seen a lot of attention for some reason and someone actually visited our blog for 11 minutes! The number of views is as dramatic but we have reached 6 visitors in one day. We also have a one visitor per day average.

Thus, we are doing well for a blog that hasn't seen anything really new for a few months. I will do another update in a month (April 12-13, 2017) for our monthly 30 day summary!

## Status: Doing great!

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! I'll see about writing a new post in the next few days. (weeks?) :D